# How to idiomatically transform nullable types in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin, and I am looking for advises rewriting the following code to more elegant way.

```
val ts: Long? = 1481710060773

val date: Date?
if (ts != null) {
    date = Date(ts)
}
```

I have tried `let`, but I think it is not better than the original one.

```
val ts: Long? = 1481710060773

val date: Date?
ts?.let {
    date = Date(ts)
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your first snipped must not have compiled, since it is an impossible code in Kotlin (`val date` is not always initialised). Please correct it or make it more specific

Comment: I'm sure it's compilable (at least it works in Android Studio with Kotlin 1.0.5-2).

Comment: @voddan It's perfectly possible to declare but not initialize a `val`. The only point where compilation errors may occur is accessing it before it is assigned, and trying to assign it more than once. [Defining local variables](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#defining-local-variables).

Comment: @iForests yes, it compiles, but given that code alone, you can't use `date` in any way. Please make the code complete. In other words, there must be an alternative assignment to `date` in case `ts` is a `null`. I am not being pedantic here ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use result of [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) call like so:

```
val date = ts?.let(::Date)
```

You can find more about function references using `::` syntax in [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references)

Comment: IMHO this is a very cryptic solution. It is most certainly not idiomatic.

Answer (score -1):

```
val ts = 1481710060773L
val date = Date(ts)
```

You don't need to specify `ts` as a nullable long type `Long?` if you are assigning a constant value to it. Then the type `Long` is inferred to `ts` and no null-check is necessary anymore.